# increase of Image size when uploading the image to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-processing

I am currently uploading an image to my Amazon S3 bucket using POST Method via an application fronted by API. Extention of the Images are PNG, JPG, and JPEG. When I'm uploading the Image which is originally 1MB,

[image]

after upload it becomes 4.6MB.

[image]

When uploading to s3 bucket the image the size of the image increases by 4 times.

I have searched, and there are many similar questions posted but i did not find a solution on how to decrease the size or just to make it increase only a minor

I have tried using different extensions (PNG, JPEG, JPG) but it is the same on every extension.

I have also tried to compress the image before uploading it but it's of no use the size is still increasing. I have checked there is no Metadata attached to it.

i have already went though this link but it was of no help: https://saturncloud.io/blog/why-does-my-image-size-increase-by-4-times-when-uploaded-to-s3-bucket-a-deep-dive/

In the future, i want to process and resize those images and after processing the size will surely increase but I don't want it to be increased 4 times

please let me know a possible solution

i'm using this code to upload :

```
public async Task uploadOnAmazonAsync(IAmazonS3 client, string fileExtension, long galleryId, string imageFolder, string imageName, string imageType, Image imgFile)
{
    try
    {
        var bucketName = _awsSettings.Value.BucketName;

        string folderName = _awsSettings.Value.FolderName + "/" + galleryId.ToString() + "/" + imageFolder + "/";


    var findFolderRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request();
    findFolderRequest.BucketName = bucketName;
    findFolderRequest.Prefix = folderName;
    findFolderRequest.MaxKeys = 1;

    ListObjectsV2Response findFolderResponse =
       await client.ListObjectsV2Async(findFolderRequest);


    if (!findFolderResponse.S3Objects.Any())
    {
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
            ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None,
            Key = folderName,
            ContentBody = string.Empty,
        };


        client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    }
    bucketName += @"/" + _awsSettings.Value.FolderName + "/" + galleryId.ToString() + "/" + imageFolder + "";


    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    imgFile.Save(memoryStream, CommonFunction.GetImageFormat(fileExtension));

    var documentName = imageName;


    var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
    {
        InputStream = memoryStream,
        Key = documentName,
        BucketName = bucketName,

    };
    uploadRequest.Headers.ContentDisposition = "attachment";
    var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

    await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);

}
catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
{
    if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null
        && (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") || amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
    {
        throw new Exception("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

}

#endregion